# JS: Performing another keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I press the Tab key, I would want that it performs another action besides the default event. I've selected a text box and I want it to add some spaces (Just wanting a textarea to act like a text editor). How to trigger this type of event?

So far, I only know how to prevent the default action:

```
    $('#content').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.which == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
    }});
```

But how do you fire another keyboard event?

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/x4jXg/

Comment: This is concatenating the spaces, therefore the spaces are being found at the end of the whole textarea.

Comment: Yes, if you want to add the spaces at the caret, that's not really hard to do, there are hundreds of answers on SO on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to preform any action. Just change value manually: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kEbY7/3/)**

```
$('#content').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 9) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        val += '        ';
        $(this).val(val);
        e.preventDefault();
}});
```